# why "\t" is counted as character and "\l" is not counted as character.When both are special variables?

Tags: perl, scalar

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

$\="\n";
my $var='WELCOME TO PERL';
$var='HI ' . $var;
print "$var";
print length $var;

$var="\t" . $var;
print $var;
print length $var;

$var="\l" . $var;
print $var;
print length $var;
```

output:

```
HI WELCOME TO PERL
18
    HI WELCOME TO PERL
19
    HI WELCOME TO PERL
19
```

Here when I concatenated `\t` to the string count is incremented by one but when I concatenated `\l` the count is not incremented. What is the difference between them.

Actually what I need is to place the `\L`  at starting of the string. So I need not to use it in `print`.

Comment: I know `\t` is a TAB, what is `\l` supposed to escape?

Answer (score 4):

See this simple test: `perl -wle '$var="\lA"; print length $var; print $var;'`

The secret is that [`\l`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#All-the-sequences-and-escapes) is an escape sequence that produces lower case of the next character.

TBH, I find it odd that it functions in string interpolation instead of just in REs.

**UPDATE**

If you change your code from `"\l"` to `'\l'` then *two* characters are inserted as expected.

Comment: Re:`I find it odd that it functions in string interpolation instead of just in REs.` http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lcfirst.html `=> This is the internal function implementing the \l escape in double-quoted strings.`

Comment: `\l` *doesn't* function in regular expressions — *only* in double-quoted strings. If you're thinking of substitutions `s///` then the left-hand side is processed as a double-quoted string first, including interpolating variables and taking account of escapes like `\l`, `\Q` etc. and then compiled as a regex, by which time `\l` has disappeared. The right hand side — the replacement text — is just a double-quoted string anyway

Comment: @ikegami: Because the pattern has first been processed as a double-quoted string, as I said. In fact, if it *did* have an effect in patterns then you would see `(?^u:\lA)`

Comment: @ikegami: If the only difference is that `\t` is carried through then it's a slim one

Comment: The parsing process is described in [Gory details of parsing quoted constructs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs) which says, ***Processing of \Q , \U , \u , \L , \l , \F , \E , and interpolation happens (almost) as with qq// constructs***

Comment: @ikegami, compare perl -E "say 'a' =~ qr'\lA'; say '\lA' =~ qr'\lA'". I think that clearly demonstrates that \l does not function (that way) in regex literals. :)

Comment: … mind you, `perl -E "say qr'\lA'"` gives a bad stringification.  I'm of half a mind to perlbug it …